# RGBDSLAM Fuerte rosmake problem

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have been fighting to rosmake the RGBDSLAM tutorial, and I have fixed many problems already. However, I am stuck at this point. I have checked the many other errors that are being asked about, and this doesn't seem to have come up. Does anyone know how to fix the following errors from the build (it looks like I am missing a stack or something)?

/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void GLViewer::paintGL()’:
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:176:45: error: ‘gluPerspective’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void GLViewer::resizeGL(int, int)’:
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:234:41: error: ‘gluPerspective’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp: In member function ‘void GLViewer::pointCloud2GLStrip(pointcloud_type*)’:
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:340:36: error: ‘hasValidXYZ’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:342:36: error: ‘hasValidXYZ’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:345:35: error: ‘hasValidXYZ’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:366:38: error: ‘hasValidXYZ’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:398:33: error: ‘hasValidXYZ’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:423:33: error: ‘hasValidXYZ’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp: In member function ‘void GLViewer::pointCloud2GLList(const pointcloud_type*)’:
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:494:33: error: ‘hasValidXYZ’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:498:33: error: ‘hasValidXYZ’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:502:31: error: ‘hasValidXYZ’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:509:31: error: ‘hasValidXYZ’ was not declared in this scope
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp: In member function ‘bool GLViewer::setClickedPosition(int, int)’:
/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:585:91: error: ‘gluUnProject’ was not declared in this scope
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/glviewer.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/virus/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/build'

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40254/rgbdslam-fuerte-rosmake-problem/) by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-07-31

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) on 2012-08-01**:
Thank you for the reply. The post you have linked is what I have used to solve many of the problems up to this point, however the missing declarations in glviewer don't seem to have been addressed yet. I was hoping someone could give me some more information about what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RGBDSLAM is not yet released to Fuerte.

You may get some help from [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/38989/rgbdslam-with-ros-fuerte-installed/).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1